# CodePipeline Deploying SAM Template Error With Added Action

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I have a `SAM` template with the resources to create a lambda function and an api gateway. The template is saved along with the code for the lambda function and the `buildspec.yaml` file. When I run the code through `codepipeline` without the api gateway resources the `SAM` template is transformed then deployed successfully. When I include the resources necessary to create the api gateway I am presented with the following error upon creation:

```
AccessDenied. User doesn't have permission to call apigateway:GetResources
```

when I look at the policy attached to the cloudformation role I have the following:

```
Actions:
  - apigateway:DELETE
  - apigateway:GetResources
  - apigateway:GetRestApis
  - apigateway:POST
Effect: Allow
Resource: !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:apigateway:*::/*"
```

The action has `apigateway:GetResources` defined yet it still fails. When I permit all api gateway actions the template is successfully deployed by `codepipeline` and `cloudformation`. That is if I have the following statement:

```
Actions:
  - apigateway:*
Effect: Allow
Resource: !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:apigateway:*::/*"
```

**Question**: Is it possible to have `codepipeline` with `cloudformation` create an api gaetway without providing the catchall(*) api gateway actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no such actions in API gateway IAM policies like:

```
  - apigateway:GetResources
  - apigateway:GetRestApis
```

The API gateway permissions have the [form](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies-to-create-and-manage-api.html#api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies) of:

```
apigateway:HTTP_VERB
```

So you probably need `GET`:

```
Actions:
  - apigateway:DELETE
  - apigateway:GET
  - apigateway:POST
```

Comment: I noticed that as well in the IAM, but assumed that I might have overlooked something. Is there any way to add those actions to give cloudformation the least privileges to create and deploy an api gateway based on a SAM template?

Comment: @Lukasz You can limit to specific resource, instead of using wildcards. But I don't think you can have more gradual actions then GET, POST ....